# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method: addRenderKitClass() on object: org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.RenderKit

Tags: myfaces, websphere-8

Got "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method: addRenderKitClass() on object: org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.RenderKit" exception while deploying myfaces 1.2 application to websphere 8.0. Seems to be similar to https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014782514.

It looks like it is caused by RenderKit and DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl loaded from different jsf libs. Running server with "Verbose class loading" confirms this:

```
me@mycomp:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/PROF1/logs/server1# grep org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.RenderKit native_stderr.log 
class load: org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.RenderKit from: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.jsf.myfaces.jar
class load: org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.RenderKit from: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/PROF1/installedApps/myNode03Cell/mnu-ear.ear/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-1.2.5.jar
class load: org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.RenderKit from: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/PROF1/installedApps/myNode03Cell/mnu-ear.ear/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-1.2.5.jar
class load: org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements.RenderKit from: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/PROF1/installedApps/myNode03Cell/mnu-ear.ear/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-1.2.5.jar
```

and then

```
my@mycomp:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/PROF1/logs/server1# grep DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl native_stderr.log 
class load: org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl from: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.jsf.myfaces.jar
```

thus the DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl is loaded only from IBM's jsf while RendererKit is loaded from all possible locations.

So the question is how to get DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl loaded from custom jsf lib.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran across this same issue. It seems to be caused by some faces-config.xml files in the WAR/EAR that do not conform to the version the server expects (which is 2.0 as of WAS 8).

In our scenario this SHOULD not be a problem as we bundle our own version of JSF with the WAR and have the class loader policy for both the EAR and the WAR contained in that EAR set to local classloader first, and the bundled JSF version is 1.2. However, removing all the version and DTD information from the header of the faces-config.xml files solved the issue for us.